# POPUP calendar in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

so what I'm trying to do is to make a popup calendar by textbox by using datepicker. the problem that I faced is the calendar doesn't popup at all .

below  is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

        <script  type ="text/javascript" >
            //   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(function () {
                //initialise the datepicker with the date format specified
                $(".datepicker").datepicker();

        </script>
```

next:

```
 <input id="txtSche1" type="text"  CssClass="datepicker" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Comment: Check any JavaScript error in browser developer console.

Comment: Change `CssClass` to `class`. `CssClass` is an aspnet Control property.

Comment: `CssClass` attribute property only available for server controls. For standard input `class` attribute should be used.

Comment: already change the cssClass to class. the result remain unchanged. The popup calendar still not functioning

Comment: Put `jquery-1.x.x.js` script tag on the top before `jquery-ui.js` script. The jQuery library must be loaded first before UI script which controls datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I try other method but but this time I'm using image button and it worked

```
   $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtSche1]").datepicker({
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: '../images/PopUpSmallCalendar.gif',

        });
    });
```

I also remove the class from the text input

```
<input id="txtSche1" type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
```